# How to handle POST data in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am working on a project with `yii2` framework and I am having problem handling `$_POST` data in `controller`. I am using following code to access the data

```
public function actionUser()
{
    $this->layout = 'app';

    $request = Yii::$app->request;

    $id= $request->post('user_id');

    $name= $request->post('name');
    $address= $request->post('address');

    if($id != null){

        if($name !=null && $address!=null){
            $query = new Query();
            $query  ->select(['u.*'])
                ->from('user u')
                ->where('name ='.$name);

            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,

            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('user' ,['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
    }
 }
```

But when I test it using `Postman` it gives `Bad request error`

So is the any other way to handle data in `controller` or I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Provide more information: How is the action called, what is the action's method signature, are there any filters in your controller? Provide some code please.

Comment: @robsch I have updated the question

Comment: Is this action called at all? I guess the error is before calling it. Can you provide the stack trace (in the log file)? What is the called URL? Do you have any filters in your controller? What is the name of the class? Is it placed in a module? Provide more information, please.

Comment: This error can happen when you don't provide CSRF token with the post data.